# How can I create two separate bundles with vue-cli 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I want to build two separate vue apps that will be served on two different routes in an express application: a ‘public’ vue app and an ‘admin’ vue app. These two apps have their own router and store but they share a lot of custom components.
How can I edit the default webpack template to make it output two separate bundles based of my two different entry points (‘public’ and ‘admin’)?
The goal would be to end up with a setup more or less like this:

```
my-app/
+- ...
+- dist/
|  +- admin/         Admin bundle and files
|  +- public/        Public bundle and files
+- src/
|  +- components/    Shared components
|  +- admin/         Entry point, router, store... for the admin app
|  +- public/        Entry point, router, store... for the public app
+- ...
```

Must by available 2 dev servers http://localhost:8080/admin and  http://localhost:8080/public
Each project must be in own folder in dist, and own public

What i have today:
created file vue.config.js  in root directory
With:

```
module.exports = {
  // tweak internal webpack configuration.
  // see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/webpack.md
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // If you wish to remove the standard entry point
    config.entryPoints.delete('app')

    // then add your own
    config.entry('admin')
      .add('./src/admin/index.js')
      .end()
    .entry('public')
      .add('./src/public/index.js')
      .end()
  }
}
```

Comment: Every get a solution for this?

Answer (score 31):

Assuming you need completely separate builds, with some shared scripts guided by your entries, you can add separate build commands.

In your package.json "scripts" section:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:admin": "vue-cli-service build --dest dist/admin src/admin/index.js,
    "build:public": "vue-cli-service build --dest dist/public src/public/index.js
}
```

For admin builds, you may run:

```
npm run build:admin
```

and for public builds:

```
npm run build:public
```

For more information, view the [build target docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html).

Comment: This is very useful when used with vue-cli 3's `pages` to keep your pages output directory completely separate.

Comment: When using `vue-cli-service` it's good to use `--no-clean`, otherwise `dist` directory is removed on each build.

Comment: Beware that if you follow this approach and are trying to keep files that only admin requires (e.g Vuetify) you will find that public will also contain the Vuetify JS/CSS in the bundle. The fix is to have 2 separate vue.config.js files one with the index section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50820261/908677 and another with the admin section. Then you'll truly have complete separation when building the compiled apps. The strange thing is when using "npm run serve" a single vue.config.js file works just fine without causing admin-only vendor libs to leak into the other one.

Comment: @ElijahLofgren I didn't understand very well this reply. Where should I put those two different vue.config.js files? And what goes in each of them? Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: @EduardoC.K.Ferreira I ended up making a separate folder and putting the 2 versions of vue.config.js in that folder. Then I made 2 bat files that each do the following: 1. Copy one of the config files (e.g. vue.adminConfig.js) from that directory. 2. Delete the original vue.config.js 3. Rename the vue.adminConfig.js file to vue.config.js and 4. Finally run the specific build command e.g. npm run build:admin

Comment: I forgot to mention what those 2 config files contain in my case (I have "admin" and "main" instead of "admin" and "public). You can see that here: https://gist.github.com/ejlofgren/0f8368b5c0a74ebc94604558303a73e7 and for reference I also included a portion of my package.json file under "snippet of package.json scripts" in that gist.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, here is an example of @ElijahLofgren idea, but using node commands to copy+paste+rename files, all together if the respective build commands: https://gist.github.com/educkf/97e76da8d8c2b5dad17846a7d576e205

Comment: @EduardoC.K.Ferreira thank you for sharing! I have only one problem. Want to use different templates per page. I have `public/index.html` and `public/admin.html` and when I build for pdf only, it contains only `vendors-chunk.js` inside and no `app.js`. I need completely separate `vendors-chunk.js and `common-chunk.js` for index and pdf.

Comment: I cant make it work. Every time I generate, it generate BOTH, public and private, even though are separate...

Answer (score 22):

I am also very interested by this matter.

Maybe we can solve this issue with subpages :

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages :
"Build the app in multi-page mode. Each "page" should have a corresponding JavaScript entry file. The value should be an object where the key is the name of the entry, and the value is either:"

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      // entry for the *public* page
      entry: 'src/index/main.js',
      // the source template
      template: 'public/index.html',
      // output as dist/index.html
      filename: 'index.html'
    },
    // an admin subpage 
    // when using the entry-only string format,
    // template is inferred to be `public/subpage.html`
    // and falls back to `public/index.html` if not found.
    // Output filename is inferred to be `admin.html`.
    admin: 'src/admin/main.js'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to have multiple `vue.config.js` configs and switch them over using the `VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.

For example, we can have a default `vue.config.js` and an additional `vue.public.config.js` and run the build like this:

```
# Build using vue.config.public.js
# Note: using real path here, it didn't work with relative path
CONF=`realpath vue.config.public.js`
VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH=$CONF npm run build

# Build using default vue.config.js
npm run build
```

Where `npm run build` is defined in `package.json` as `vue-cli-service build`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
}
```

Note: I didn't find any mention on `VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH` in the documentation, found it looking at the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/a1041a897e4e9e57924bb6a2bfffde5db1d87ae7/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js#L323).

Answer (score 4):

Building on the other answers here, I've found it's possible to specify the build output directory in vue.config.js rather than having to do that in the command line. So then combining that with the use of the `VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable makes things a lot simpler - no need for it to copy/delete config files each time you build.

You do have to specify the full paths to the Vue config files though. This works even on Windows, but only from a Linux-type terminal (e.g. I tested it from Git Bash installed by Git for Windows and it worked fine, but doesn't work from the normal Windows Command Prompt, as I couldn't find any way of setting the environment variable in the npm script which worked when run from there)

https://gist.github.com/EdwardMillen/0c417747cd8ce64b8ba550bdfa582cf5

Comment: I've looked at this answer before, but just clicking your link. I struggled with making the scripts run in Powershell/CMD with a && alternative (npm-run-all etc).  If I'd just read the whole answer, would have saved me so much time using the git bash.

Comment: use git cmd then